# Django inner join

Tags: django

I am having some difficulties with the usage of django query. Basically I am trying to perform an inner join between Tutor_info(user,contact,etc.) and UserProfile(user,points,etc.) which is joined by the 'user' column. The result will be ordered by 'points' column in the UserProfile in the descending order producing an ordered Tutor_info object list.

I'm unsure of how to produce an ordering of the Tutor_info list using an attribute  on another table--UserProfile table.

Should I be doing something as follows?

```
tutors_list = Tutor_info.objects.all() 
for t in tutors_list:
    UserProfile.objects.filter(user=t.user)
    ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django does the inner join implicitly if you  try to filter/order by on a foreign column. So this will work:

```
tutors_list = Tutor_info.objects.all().order_by('-user__points')
```

Or this if you join through the `auth.User` model (thanks to Daniel Roseman):

```
tutors_list = Tutor_info.objects.all().order_by('-user__userprofile__points')
```

Comment: Not quite, because `points` is on `UserProfile`, not `User`. Think you need `user__userprofile__points`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: possibly, but that was not specified :) Hard to say which is correct, I'll add both just to be sure.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot! using 'user__userprofile__points' worked. :-)